# Issue with S3 Uploads in Dockerized Django App on ECS

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-ecs

I'm facing an issue with S3 uploads in my Dockerized Django application running on AWS ECS. The setup includes RDS and S3, and I've successfully tested file uploads locally using docker run and Postman.

However, when I create a task definition, launch an ECS EC2 cluster with a load balancer and a target group, and attempt to upload a file to S3, I'm encountering a 504 Gateway Timeout error. In the logs, I see the message 'Loading s3:s3,' and the service breaks, then reloads.

for IAM i add S3FullAccess to all IAM related to my ecs
in security groups i allow all traffic (inbound, outbound)

in security groups i allow all traffic (inbound, outbound)

Added the AmazonS3FullAccess policy to the ecsTaskExecutionRole IAM role associated with ECS tasks.
Confirmed IAM role changes have propagated.

Checked the trust relationship of the ecsTaskExecutionRole to allow ECS to assume the role.

Answer (score 0):

> Added the AmazonS3FullAccess policy to the ecsTaskExecutionRole IAM role associated with ECS tasks. Confirmed IAM role changes have propagated.
>
> Checked the trust relationship of the ecsTaskExecutionRole to allow ECS to assume the role.

The Task Execution Role is what the ECS Service itself assumes, in order to have the permissions it needs to create your ECS task. The ECS task will have a separate [Task IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) that it will assume, which gives your code running inside the task access to AWS services. This role is optional, so you may not even have one defined yet. This is what you need to setup in order to provide your code running in ECS the permissions to access other AWS services like S3.